# Images not showing in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I am new to Magento and php. I am displaying the slideshow in my test page. It's working on Internet Explorer, but it's not showing on Google Chrome and Firefox.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, or what I can do to debug it?

Comment: This will be impossible to debug, unless yu give some code examples, and at leats the html that was produced for your img element.

Comment: It might be a cache problem, but as said, we can't do much with the information provided.